# DB and web server on separate providers machines

Tags: php, mysql, server, communication

I am moving my servers so I am going to have my web application running for a month with database on different provider servers. Servers geographical distance is small (the same city).

- DB server  - PDO MySql
- Web server - Zend PHP

Will I have problems with communication between these web and db server? What are major things to pay attention to?

Comment: Yes you will. Major thing to pay attention to is the latency time between two servers. the can stay in the next rack mounts but the latency time could be unacceptable big

Comment: Thanks. I have measured latency between servers and it is 40ms. What latency is acceptable for mysql or generally for server communication?

Comment: @Agape 40ms is fine, I don't know how many users you have on your web application but as long as you're not in the 1000's you shouldn't have a problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably account for more latency, it will mostly depend on the quality of the connection in between the servers but it could still be pretty reasonable.

You will have to set an account up on the remote database host which can actually login from your ip address, and probably whitelist your server's ip in general on that server to prevent others from connecting.

The rest won't change much, just the usual:

-use prepared statements

-validate the input

-don't trust your users

-etc

Apart from that, I'd be considering taking a more regular look at the logs to make sure that everything runs smoothly and that you make regular backups just in case you need to set up an emergency server if something goes wrong.